# How do I compile Autoconf from git without already having Autoconf

Tags: autoconf

I am on an OS that doesn't currently have Autoconf so I am trying to install from source using `git clone git://git.sv.gnu.org/autoconf` but there is no configure in that folder. I know there are other ways like using a package manager or downloading the tar version with the existing configure file.

But how do I compile Autoconf if I don't already have autoconf installed?

Comment: If you are on a somewhat barebones system, you should get the tarball *distribution* of Autoconf which will have a `configure` file. The sources in the VCS are usually not meant to include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how do I compile Autoconf if I don't already have autoconf installed?

Install `autoconf` from a tarball or package manager and follow the steps in `README-hacking`, e.g.:

```
$ autoreconf -vi
```

will generate `configure`.  Implicity, the answer to your question is: you don't, if you follow the steps in `README-hacking`.

I've always grabbed a tarball if a package wasn't available on a platform to get a working copy of `autoconf`.

Comment: So what you are saying is I cannot compile it without 1) installing autoconf from a binary instead of source. Or 2 manually create a configure file or even 3) copy configure from the tar ball found on the ftp site. No way to do it just from the source itself?

Comment: I can appreciate the answer but what if I edited the kernel or something so it never had a valid binary? Grab the closest config from a tar and modify?

Comment: 1) I'm not saying it's impossible to somehow install `autoconf` without following the steps in `README-hacking` (e.g. without a previous version of `autoconf` already installed).  But this is what the _developers_ of `autoconf` recommend.  They consider checkouts to be alpha quality software anyway (e.g. `README-alpha`), so possibly introducing even more breakage via 2) and 3) sounds like a bad idea.  I wouldn't really characterize `autoconf` as a "binary" really, it's a `sh` script.

Comment: should be autoreconf here, -vi is invalid option for autoconf

Answer (score 0):

After cloning the source code, call `./bootstrap`. It will generate a configure file for you. Now just call `./configure` with its parameters.